# Autoplay audio with jPlayer

Tags: javascript, jplayer

Recently I purchased this handy script from codecanyon called "[Flatie](https://cdn.prahec.com/project/flatie-jplayer-skin)", it works for literally every new project I have except I have stumbled into a dead end in terms of getting the audio to autoplay.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#player4").flatie({
     media: {
     mp3: "http://www.example.com/mp3embed-song-name.mp3"
  },
     swfPath: "http://www.example.com/jplayer.swf"
  });
});
</script>
```

Here's the current Javascript I am using (This is all I have ever needed + including the JavaScript file found [here](https://cdn.prahec.com/projects/flatie-jplayer-skin/skin/flatie.jplayer.skin.min.js).)

When I used the standard method shown on the [jPlayer documentation](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-play) for autoplaying it makes my player disappear.

(*I am a complete noob when it comes to Javascript so I have no idea what I am doing wrong.*)

Comment: I didn't mean to submit that, but can you show how you included it within your code?

Comment: @dcclassics click here http://www.ixclusives.com/f/audio.php?mp3=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/210689712/stream?client_id=e503d96cf90df4a1c81c2300ebc2e431

Comment: It's a little tricky because I'm not sure if flatie is exactly the same as jPlayer, but something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/xwzjqdoc/) is supposed to make it autoplay.  Taken from [here](http://jplayer.org/latest/quick-start-guide/example-audio-soundtrack/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var stream = {
        //title: "ABC Jazz",
        mp3: "path/../Wolf.mp3"
    },
    ready = false;

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            ready = true;
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream);
            $(this).jPlayer("play", 1);
        },
        pause: function() {
            $(this).jPlayer("clearMedia");
        },
        error: function(event) {
            if(ready && event.jPlayer.error.type === $.jPlayer.error.URL_NOT_SET) {
                // Setup the media stream again and play it.
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream).jPlayer("play");
            }
        },

    swfPath: "path/../jPlayer/dist/jplayer",
    supplied: "mp3",
    preload: "none",
    volume: 1,
    wmode: "window",
    useStateClassSkin: true,
    autoBlur: false,
    keyEnabled: true
  });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the following option "autoPlay: true"?
        },

```
    swfPath: "/js",
    supplied: "mp3, m4a, oga" ,
    autoPlay: true
});
```